# C++ showing a string

Tags: c++, cout

Actually am kind of new to c++. i want to display "Questions" if answers is more than one and "Question" if answers in below one
these are they errors i get

```
    5   IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << std::string  c:\Users\Ugwu\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Chrysohgomus_Ugwu_A4\Chrysohgomus_Ugwu_A4\mathTutor.cpp 46  39  Chrysohgomus_Ugwu_A4
```

Or [Image Link](http://www.4shared.com/download/Q7eViSk1ba/Screenshot__17__-_Copy.png?lgfp=3000)

This is my code

```
string Question;

void grade() {
    question = correct + incorrect;
    if (question > 1){ 
        Question = "Questions";
    }
    else{
        Question = "Question"; 
    }
    cout << "Out Of " << question << " " << Question << " You Got " << correct << " Correct " << "And " << incorrect << " Incorrect " << endl;
}
```

can someone show me the right way?

Comment: What is `correct` and what is `incorrect`?

Comment: Did you include the required standard library headers? I would avoid having two variables whose name differ only in case. Without a compiling example to test I cannot help any further.

Comment: use Question.c_str() instead of Question in cout

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Why would that solve the problem? You can cout a string.

Comment: Don't use a global variable for this. If you want to use a variable, make it a local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is that either correct or incorrect are not objects that are printable by cout.

It's also possible that you haven't included `<string>` correctly in your program. Did you add `#include <string>` and `using std` in your code?

(Granted, I don't really support the idea of `using std`, but if you're going to use `string` without the `std::` prefix, you have to add `using std`. Personally, I think you'd be better off sticking to `std::string`.)

Comment: @NeilKirk Good point - I've retracted that until he provides more data.

Comment: @ChrysAugunus At the very least, we need to know whether you've included std::string correctly, and what the types of correct and incorrect are. The problem is obviously that you're trying to `cout` a type that can't be `cout`'ed, so we need to know the types you're dealing with.

Comment: i Just Included String and it Worked

Comment: @ChrysAugunus If by "it Worked" you mean my answer fixed your problem, please check the answer to select it.